# How can I animate a recursive algorithm?

Tags: graphics, algorithm, animation, timer

Say I have a recursive algorithm, for example one that generates a random tree:

```
// Pseudocode, just a simple algorithm: it isn't perfect.
function generate_branch(angle, length, current_depth, max_depth) {
  var branch = Branch(angle, length); // creates a new branch
  if (current_depth == max_depth) {
    return branch;
  }
  current_depth++;
  // random_int(min, max)
  branch.subbranches[] = generate_branch(random_int(0, angle + random_int(-30, 30)),
                                         random_int(0, 20)
                                         current_depth,
                                         max_depth);
  // ^^^^ recursion
  return branch;
}

var trunk = generate_branch(0, random_int(10), 0, 5);
RenderTree(trunk);
```

The problem is that this will render the entire tree in one frame. If I want to animate this (i.e. grow the tree over time), how would I do that? What is the best way to do this?

The game uses a game loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You store the current depth of every branch for each node, and append Rendertree to render all nodes up to a specific depth, given as a parameter.

This way, you can show each depth level seperatly.

Pseudocode could be like this:

```
Generate tree

While(GameLoopRunning)
  begin
    for i := 0 to maxdepth do
      begin
        RenderTree(trunk, i)
        delay(250); //should not be like this, will block entire game loop.         
      end
  end
```

Edit:
You might want to use some kind of timer to fire some kind of GrowNow!-Events to your game logic in order to avoid the for-loop and delay in your main game loop.

Comment: Good idea. I can put the "GrowNow!-Event" in the `Step()` method of the tree. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: You could also have the generation and drawing on seperate threads.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is save a stack of the process you need to do (with all the parameters and depth), and only process one branch at a time, which will add one or more other branch to the stack.

This way you'll draw one step at a time. Of course you can choose to process more than one branch from the stack at a time or wait a delay between each process.